# Dynamically created HTML table opens new page

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, for-loop

I've got a code, a math table coder actually.. If anybody presses the button, the function is called and is running.. But when i click the button, the table is coming on a new page instead in the same page..

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tafel Trainer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="content">
    <p>Wilt u de tafels leren? Klik op de knop oefenen</p>
    <button id="oefenen" name="oefenen" value="oefenen" onclick='oefenen()';>Tafel oefenen!</button>
<div id="1">
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function oefenen(){
            var num = prompt("Zet een cijfer neer", "0");
            var num1 = parseInt(num); 



                for(i= 1; i< 11; i++) {
                    document.writeln("<table border='1'><tr><td>" + i + " x " + num1 + " = " + i * num1 + "<br/></td></tr></table>");
                                    }

                    }   

</script>

</div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I've already tried to do it with document.getElementByID('div1').innerHTML = i; But that code also didn't work, im sure its a beginners fault but what :)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to use a more conventional method than [`document.write`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp). Try [`appendChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp) or [`innerHTML`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Let me try, thnx for the fast reply:)

Comment: It didn't work, I just want it under the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have a lot more control over what you are doing if you have a `div` placeholder for your table eg

```js
function oefenen(){
 var num = prompt("Zet een cijfer neer", "0");
 var num1 = parseInt(num); 
 var table = document.getElementById("tablebody");

 for(var i= 1; i< 11; i++) {
  var td = document.createElement("td"); //create TD
  td.innerHTML = i + " x " + num1 + " = " + (i * num1);
  var tr = document.createElement("tr");
  tr.appendChild(td); //add TD to the TR
  table.appendChild(tr); //add TR to the table
 }
                //show the placeholder
 document.getElementById("placeholder").style.display = ""; 
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
<p>Wilt u de tafels leren? Klik op de knop oefenen</p>
<button id="oefenen" name="oefenen" value="oefenen" onclick='oefenen()';>Tafel oefenen!   </button>
<div id="1"> <!-- I'm not sure what you use this div for -->
</div>
<div id="placeholder" style="display:none;"> <!-- Placeholder area -->
 <table border="1" id="tablebody"></table>
<div>
</section>
```

Notice also how I `var` the `i` in the loop - otherwise you create a reference to `i` at the window-level, rather than just scoped to the function.

Also, the use of `createElement` may look long-winded - but when you come to creating mark-up of any complexity it is much preferred to setting innerHTML and concatenating strings etc. It is certainly easier to trace what is going on and break sections out into other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Works ok here. ## EDITED after above comments about wanting it under the button

```js
function oefenen() {
  var num = prompt("Zet een cijfer neer", "0");
  var num1 = parseInt(num);

  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML+=("<tr><td>" + i + " x " + num1 + " = " + i * num1 + "<br/></td></tr>");
  }

}
```

```html
<section id="content">
  
  <p>Wilt u de tafels leren? Klik op de knop oefenen</p>
  
  <button id="oefenen" name="oefenen" value="oefenen" onclick='oefenen()' ;>Tafel oefenen!</button>
  
  <table border="1" id=
"results">
    </table>
  
</section>
```

Comment: It works, but I want it in the same page.. Or is this in the same page? I've got a blackout i guess.
Just under the button maybe..

Comment: Been off SO for a while and this is the first time I've seen a code snippet! Awesome!!

Comment: Why would you create 11 tables with 1 cell in each ?

Answer (score -1):

*"If you execute the document.write() method on a loaded HTML document, all HTML elements will be overwritten"* says [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

```
I think it is better to use innerHTML
```

Comment: You're writing 11 tables to the page instead of 1.

Answer (score -1):

code as per your requirement to print the multiplication table for required number ....

```
     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tafel Trainer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
   <section id="content">

  <p>Wilt u de tafels leren? Klik op de knop oefenen</p>

  <button id="oefenen" name="oefenen" value="oefenen" onclick='oefenen()' ;>Tafel oefenen!</button>
  <br />  <br />
  <div id="math">

  </div>

</section>
<script>
function oefenen() {
  var num = prompt("Zet een cijfer neer", "0");
  var num1 = parseInt(num);

  for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    document.getElementById('math').innerHTML+=(num1 + " x " + i + " = " + i * num1 + "<br/>");}

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you adding tr's and td's to a div.

Comment: Actually I just customized his code, and forget to remove those tags.I edited the code to print correct multiplication table..Thanq..@Billy